# Is there a preferred way how to post a question and the answer in one step?

Tags: support, instant-self-answer

Sometimes I have an issue, for which I can not find a solution/answer on your platform. Then later I find the solution/answer by my self. If I then think that this knowledge could help other developers, is there a preferred way how I can post the question and the answer in only one step? Or should I post it as a normal question and quickly answer it in a second post?

Answer (score 3):

You can always [ask and answer your own questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Just tick *Answer your own question* checkbox to get the answer text area while asking a question.

> [image]